# PHP Sending Arrays with Mail()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to send the contents of an array through mail, I have tried the print_r method however do not really like the way it is formatted in the email, so I tried the implode, however currently it is not actually sending the content, rather just "Array Array Array"

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user","pw", "db");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$recipient_email = "email@email.com";

$result= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE datetime_registered >=       DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9 DAY)")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$subscribers = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $subscribers[] = array(
    "uid" => $row['id'],
    "name" => $row['name'],
    "email" => $row['email'],
    "ip" => $row['ip'],
    "date_registered" => $row['datetime_registered']
    );


 }


 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
 $headers .= 'From: '.$recipient_email.''."\n";

 $subject = "Subject";
 $recipient = $recipient_email;
 $content = implode("\n", $subscribers);
 mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
 ?>
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your `$headers` variables, use this code:

```
$newSubscribers = array();
foreach($subscribers as $data)
{
    $newSubscribers[] = implode(', ', $data);
}

$newSubscribers = implode("<br>\n", $newSubscribers);
$subscribers = $newSubscribers;
```

So your end code should look like this:

```
...
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

$subscribers[] = array(
"uid" => $row['id'],
"name" => $row['name'],
"email" => $row['email'],
"ip" => $row['ip'],
"date_registered" => $row['datetime_registered']
);


}

$newSubscribers = array();
foreach($subscribers as $data)
{
    $newSubscribers[] = implode(', ', $data);
}

$newSubscribers = implode("\n<br>", $newSubscribers);
$subscribers = $newSubscribers;


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$recipient_email.''."\n";
```

Comment: Phil this is great thanks, however it is not actually putting it on a new line, how would I get a new line between each subscriber for the email?

Answer (score 3):

When you want to mail an array with print_r, fill the second parameter with true:

```
print_r($array, true);
```

See the following link for more information:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `implode` function is only imploding your top-level array which is `$subscribers`. It's not going down to the next level array data.

You could try this:

```
foreach($subscribers as $subscriber_data){
    $dataset[] = implode(', ', $subscriber_data);
}

$content = implode("\n", $dataset);
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working as you'd like is because implode() does not work with associative arrays the way you think it would.  I'd recommend:

```
$subscribers[] = array(
"uid: {$row['id']}",
"name: {$row['name']}",
...
);
```

Then when you parse this array with implode, with a newline as the delimiter, you will see

```
"uid: someid
 name: somename
 ....
"
```

Which I assume is what you're going for.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is very nice you send that array in key value pairs, instead of sending only value..

convert that using following script and send it via your email.

```
$data = '';
foreach ($subscribers as $key=>$value){
    $data .= $key.'-------'.$value;
    $data.= "\n";
}
```

send via php mail function..

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$recipient_email.''."\n";

$subject = "Subject";
$recipient = $recipient_email;
$content = $data;
mail($recipient, $subject, $content, $headers);
```